# Where is the square operation "fun**2" in the source code of “scipy.optimize.least_squares”?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

Now I need to add the regularization term to “scipy.optimize.least_squares”. Could anyone tell me where is the square operation "fun**2" in the source code of scipy?

```
scipy.optimize.least_squares(fun, x0,...)
```

Comment: `^` is XOR in Python (and in most programming languages), by the way. `**` is exponentiation in Python.

Comment: Also, don't edit the scipy source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the function loss_function, lines 219-226 or 228-235 depending on whether or not the `loss` parameter is itself a callable.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f4b5605031f738bc87ae4e193d614d525b98ffba/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py#L211) This function is called at line 826, after being gotten at [line 824](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f4b5605031f738bc87ae4e193d614d525b98ffba/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py#L824).